# How to use Yii controller located in folder rather than default `protected/controller`?

Tags: controller, yii, file-location

In Yii, when access to `<app-host>/index.php?r=<mycontroller>/<myaction>`, the framework will start to run code in `protected/controller/<MyController>Controller.php`

I want to that code to be located in another folder, says `protected/anotherFolder`, while other controllers remain as-is. How to do that?

Regards

Comment: why do you need to change the location of controllers folder from Yii built in?

Comment: As Kor has pointed out, I would like to group the logic into its own folder. A 'logic' involves controller/view/model. A module meets my need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to `mdomba` on yii forum at this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/25365-how-to-use-yii-controller-located-in-folder-rather-than-default-protectedcontroller/), I found the answer using `CWebApplication::controllerMap` - in the loading state of the application we call

```
Yii::app()->controllerMap['yourControllerName']='path.alias.to.your.controller.file.without.dotPHP';
```

> You can use controllerMap - http://www.yiiframew...ollerMap-detail

Answer (score 6):

Open up `<app-host>/index.php`, edit to

```
//...
require_once($yii);
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
$app->setControllerPath('protected/anotherFolder');
$app->run();
```

Comment: Thank you Elvan. But this will change the all controllers. I need that just for some of them

Answer (score 3):

If I got you, you want to split the web logic into different "folders", or (in a more yii-ly way) modules. For instance, to have all the administrating stuff into another place and get to this using r=admin/users, for instance

If you have your gii manager activated, go to /index.php?r=gii, and create a module. That's it. You can then create controllers inside protected/modules/`<module-name>`/controllers/ and call them using that path. Of course, views are also stored inside that

Comment: You got me well. Though, applying a `module` will change my code structure a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can add to config file

```
'controllerPath' => 'your_new_controller_path',
```

The same with view path

```
'viewPath' => 'path_to_template_folder',
```